# How to improve back-end urI security?

Tags: api, security, uri, backend

I'm using web api for my application on ASP.NET CORE

If someone see application soruce code, there is a backend url, isn't it?
Then, that guy can use my api if he succeed my application decompile

How protect that situation

I'm just stutdent, so... Just my curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authenticate your API**

If you plan on having a private API (not open to everyone), then you should force users to authenticate themselves by using an API access token. Each token should be specific to a particular user, and there should be consequences for distributing a private key (such as revoking it and blocking the person associated with it) or else people will just share them without care. This will allow users to communicate with your server and run commands or queries as they please. Assuming you have written these functions correctly, they shouldn't allow an attacker to access much beyond his given scope of given API functions (which should be queries at most).

**Document, document, document!**

You shouldn't allow users access to your source code for this. You should document your API thoroughly regarding details which methods the user can use, what sort of data it expects to receive, and what sort of data you will get back from it (including all errors, possible problems with the users request, and how to fix their requests). Make sure you heavily test these too, and make sure that you can't perform any sort of malicious actions with your API. It's also a good idea to give your documentation to another person and ask them to read it. If you've missed something important, you will know afterwards because there will be a clear gap in their knowledge of the API.

**What, not how**

Users should know **what** a function should do, but not **how** it does it. For example, I could use `/api/GetUserById`. I should know that I can get a user - I shouldn't know *how* it gets the user. The only thing I need to know is that I perform this call and I get back a json object with details about the user. That is it.

As with any of my posts, if there's something I've missed or something you need further clarification on, please let me know in the comments and I'd be happy to explain further. I hope this helps